# navigation drawer: тормоза при выбор элемента списка

Tags: android

Всем привет. В качестве меню в приложении использую navigation drawer. Всё делала согласно туториалам. При свайпе всё отлично, всё красиво, меню выдвигается и прячется на место очень гармонично. Но если я выбираю элемент из списка, то меню прячется скачками. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? В чём может быть проблема?

Что у меня есть: ParrentActivity extends ActionBarActivit,

Стандартный макет для него

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"/>
```

При выбор элемента списка открывается один из фрагментов.

```
 Fragment fragment = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    switch (position){
        case 1: fragment = NewsFeedFragment.newInstance();
            args.putString("arg","arg");
            break;
        case 2: fragment = ArticlesFragment.newInstance();
            args.putString("arg","arg");
            break;
        case 3: fragment = BlogsFragment.newInstance();
            args.putString("arg","arg");
            break;
        case 4: fragment = Research2Fragment.newInstance();
            args.putString("arg","arg");
            break;
        case 5: fragment = AuthorsFragment.newInstance();
            args.putString("arg","arg");
            break;
        default:break;
    }
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager frgManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();
```

Comment: А что странного? Замена фрагмента(наверное еще и с тяжелым VIew) - это ресурсоемкая операция, которая выполняется на том же (UI) потоке, что и анимация NavigationDrawer.

Comment: А какие есть альтернативы? чем можно заменить Navigation Drawer? Или лучше открывать новую активити, а не фрагмент?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В отдельном потоке фрагменты заменяю. Теперь всё окей.

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                selectItem(position);

            }
        }, 300);
    }
}
```